# How can i get user information in angular 7 after successful login from ADFS from my redirected page

Tags: spring-boot, angular7, adfs2.0

I am using spring boot, spring security saml, angular 7, using this lib https://github.com/choonchernlim/spring-security-adfs-saml2

My Backend deployed in tomcat 8 with port 443.

And my UI deployed in tomcat 9 with port 8181

After successful login from ADFS my UI redirected to dashboard.

From this dashboard i need username that have been authenticated by ADFS.

How can i get that username from my spring boot?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution

In my spring controller i just return username from Pricipal Object

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adfs/username", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public User getADUsername(Principal principal) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setLoginName(principal.getName());
    ...
    return user;
}
```

And My Angular i use

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable(
{
    providedIn : "root"
}
)
export class XhrInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        const xhr = req.clone({
          withCredentials: true
        });
        return next.handle(xhr);
   }
}
```

And Provide it to app.module in provider array

```
providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: XhrInterceptor, multi: true }
],
```